# send php value to another file in extjs

Tags: php, extjs4

I need to pass a value of a php variable to another file using extjs4
I have this at the top of my page:

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
```

This is my extjs code

```
echo("
{
    title: 'Users',
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    store: {
        storeId: 'test',
        fields: [
            {name: 'ID', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Admin', type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'GetScripts/getUsers.php',
            reader: 'json'
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },
```

i need to pass $userid to getUsers.php.
Can I get some help on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proxy you can specify URL parameters like so:

```
echo("
{
    title: 'Users',
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    store: {
        storeId: 'test',
        fields: [
            {name: 'ID', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Admin', type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'GetScripts/getUsers.php',
            reader: 'json',
            extraParams: { 
               userid: " . $userid . "
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },
```

Additionally, when you load your store you can pass parameters as well

```
store.load({
    params : {
       userid : whateverUserId
    }
});
```

Comment: your answer almost worked. if I use extraParams instead of baseParams it works!

Comment: Ah you are correct. It was baseParams but I think they changed it to extraParams in extjs4 if I'm not mistaken, I will edit the answer